# Apex test class for Messaging.InboundEmailHandler

Tags: apex, code-coverage, inboundemail

I created an apex classes where the 'to' field in the email address is stored in a custom field on the cases object. We want to do this for reporting purpose.

This is my apex class:

```
global class InsertToEmailadressinfield implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.inboundEmail email,Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope){
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
        String toAdd = String.join(email.toAddresses , ';');
        Case ac = new Case (Detailed_Origin__c = toadd);
        insert ac;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now of course this needs to be tested by a test class and I wrote this:

```
@isTest
private class EmailServiceExampleTest
{
    static testMethod void TestToEmailadress() 
    {
       // Create a new email and envelope object.    
       
       Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
       Messaging.InboundEnvelope env    = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();
    
       // Create Test record.
       Case Cas = new Case(Description='Test Class');
       insert Cas ;
       
       // Subject
       email.subject = 'Test Contact Email';
       **String toAddresses  = 'contact@contact.nl';**
       env.fromAddress = 'test@test.com';
       InsertToEmailadressinfield obj= new InsertToEmailadressinfield();
       obj.handleInboundEmail(email, env );
                            
    }
     
}
```

The problem now is that I get an error message on line 17: "System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null.". I can't manage to write a proper test class.

I hope someone can help me further, still a little nube in this ;)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you highlight which line of code is 17 please? (Just [edit] the question to add a comment on the line of code that is having this issue please.)

Comment: Hi @PhilW, thank you for your response. I added some ** in line 17.

       **String toAddresses  = 'contact@contact.nl';**

Comment: Did you comment the line 17 if not could you please add some more context

Comment: To me it is clear that what you have highlighted is not the line 17 against which the exception is occurring since what you highlighted could not throw an NPE.

Comment: I added some printscreens. The highlited part is line 17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the list of email addresses to `toAddresses` field.

```
 List<string> emails = new List<string>{'testbandi@gmail.com','testbandi123@gmail.com'};
```

Modify your test class as like below.

```
@istest
public class InsertToEmailadressinfieldTest {
    
   static testMethod void TestinBoundEmail()
   
   {
       // Create Test record.
       Case Cas = new Case(Description='Test Class');
       insert Cas ;
      
       Messaging.InboundEmail email = new Messaging.InboundEmail() ;
       Messaging.InboundEnvelope env = new Messaging.InboundEnvelope();
       // intialize the list string to store emails.
       List<string> emails = new List<string>{'testbandi@gmail.com','testbandi123@gmail.com'};
      
      email.subject = 'Create case';
      email.fromAddress = 'someaddress@email.com';
      //assigning the emails to toAddresses 
      email.toAddresses = emails;
      email.plainTextBody = 'email body';
      Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment attachment = new Messaging.InboundEmail.BinaryAttachment();
      attachment.body = blob.valueOf('my attachment text');
      attachment.fileName = 'textfileone.txt';
      attachment.mimeTypeSubType = 'text/plain';
      email.binaryAttachments = new Messaging.inboundEmail.BinaryAttachment[] { attachment };
     
      InsertToEmailadressinfield  testInbound=new InsertToEmailadressinfield ();
      testInbound.handleInboundEmail(email, env);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This works :) Thanks again and have a nice day.